# OpenGL Polygon Offset Fill implementation example code

Tags: opengl, polygon, java

I am working on a pure java implementation of OpenGL 1 called [jGL](https://github.com/jzy3d/jGL).

I am [missing glPolygonOffsetFill](https://github.com/jzy3d/jGL/issues/3) and am looking for an example implementation in java, c/c++ example of this GL function in order to integrate it in jGL.

Would anyone suggest a direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround suggested [at the bottom of this page](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/polygonoffset.htm) : to deal with coplanar lines and polygons, one can apply a different glDepthRange to polygon face and polygon wireframe.